# in java how to avoid multiple if else with map for isAssignableFrom

Tags: java

I would like to avoid the if else, in java this:

```
 for (Class clazz : method.getParameterTypes()) {
  if (SomeClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
      arguments[i] = onearg;
    } else if (SomeOtherClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
      arguments[i] = someotherarg;
    }
 }
```

can anyone suggest how to do this? thanks

Comment: well then you need another logic. something else other than isAssignableFrom(), but this depends on what you do with argument[i]=arg. what kind of arg is that, is it dependant on class type?

Comment: yes, users can define methods which access different subclasses of the classes i will have for them as arguments so i need to match the arguments the users have defined in their plugins for the arguments classes into a set of superclasses i knowbefore hand they are oging to use.

Comment: You can arrange a `Map<Class, Object>` where the value is the arg value to set. Then walk the `entrySet` of that map in a loop (you can `break` out as soon as you find a match).

Comment: Better not use `class` as a variable name for classes, since it's a Java keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the classes and their arguments in a `Map<Class<?>, Object>` and iterate the map, this would replace the if-else construct by an iteration loop with one if-statement.

For instance like this:

```
Map<Class<?>, Object> map = ... /* initialize */

for (Class cls : method.getParameterTypes()) {  
     for (Entry<Class<?>, Object> candidate : map.entrySet()) {
          if (candidate.getKey().isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
               arguments[i] = candidate.getValue()
               break; // continue with the next parameter type
          }
     }
}
```

The concrete implementation depends on your classes. If the classes in your map have **no relationship** between each other (e.g. superclass, subclass, interface, etc.) then you can apply the code directly. Otherwise,  as *bestsss* has pointed ought you should stick to super class/interface iteration in order to **preserve the class hierarchy**.

Further your could investigate into [Java Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html), though I am not 100% sure how to apply them in your case without further details on the requirements. You could annotate your super classes with the arguments

```
@Argument("onearg")
public class SomeClass {
     /* ... */
}
```

and get the super class of the method parameter types during iteration with [`cls.getSuperClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29) and retrieve the annotated argument value afterwards for assignment.

Comment: what's the point of the Map? if you don't use `get()` - it's just a slow Collection<Map.Entry>. More also, now there is no order of processing the classes which implies absolutely flat hierarchy (as it cannot be enforced). Last: if you change the `continue` to `break` change the appropriate comment.

Comment: @bestsss I guess `Collection<Map.Entry>` is less convenient for the average Java coder, plus you need your own implementation of `Map.Entry` to instantiate it, don't you? I tend to use map iteration over repeated `get(obj)` invocations, when you need to access the key value beforehand. What is wrong with the comment? I added it after changing `continue` to `break`, due to `break` the outer loop continues with the next parameter type of the inspected method.

Comment: @emory The OP asked for a solution to eliminate his/her if-else construct, I suspect the OP wants to avoid creating a big if-else tree with more and more classes. This way it is easier to extend if you place the map initialization at a convenient place in the code. Plus there is still the annotation strategy.

Comment: `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` is there if you need (I bet it's news it exists). however the point stands: unless using LHM, the hierarchy has to be flat. Imagine the case: ArrayList.class, List.class, Collection.class, you'd like to iterate 'em exactly in this way. Not: Collection.class, ArrayList.class, etc - since the 1st will match even though the most concrete class would be ArrayList. The better way to handle via map is iterating through the superclasses and interfaces and using get(clazz), the complexity is lower too.

Comment: thanks, however i'm pretty sure there is some way to do that without the need to do a new iteration every time i need to match arguments (efficiency) i'm pretty sure this can be avoided by creating some kind of a wrapper lets call it IsAssignableFrom which implements equals and then hashCode which will leave the replacement of the if only with map.get without any loops, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @jason, read my last comment, it's well hinted but unless you have really a lot of classes to check via `isAssignaleFrom` you solution is just fine and very easy on the eyes. Cloning the array (`method.getParameterTypes()`) is likely to be the most expensive part in the loop.